# What's the point of visibility in transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Please advise if i'm confused but is there any point of having a transition on visibility? Opacity creates a neat effect, sure. But the change none to block will be from nada to full immediately. Maybe we can spread its occurrence **sometime** in a time interval but the transition will happen all at once. Or am i mistaken?

Here's the code i'm creating. Should i keep the last three lines in the first style?

```
div.contentItem{
    border: 2px solid #00bb00;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: Beige;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 3.0s, opacity 3.0s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 3.0s, opacity 3.0s;
    -o-transition: visibility 3.0s, opacity 3.0s;
}

div.contentItemHidden{
    opacity: 0;
}

div.contentItemVisible{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Before, i had block styles in the two last clauses but that actually damaged the transition of the opacity (probably due to the fact that display: none causes the elements not to be opacitable at all).

```
div.contentItemHidden{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.contentItemVisible{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a point to having a transition on `visibility`. If you just use `opacity` on an element, that element will still be there and will block clicks and hover effects on whatever is below it. With `visibility: hidden`, the element will no longer be visible (similar to `opacity: 0`), but cannot be clicked.

Here is a link that helps to explain in more detail why using `visibility` and `opacity` together may be necessary, and how to do so correctly: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

As a side note, I noticed that you mention `visibility` in your question, but have `display` in your code. I'd like to note that there is a difference between [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) and [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). In particular, elements `visibility: hidden` are not visible but still take up space. Elements with `display: none` are not visible but do not take up space.

Comment: Ah, i thought that "visibility" was web-kit'ish for "display". Well, i stand corrected.